# Common interface between ObservableCollection and ICollectionView

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `GridView` extracted in a separate User Control, without having its own View Model or code-behind. This user control is used in two different views, which by default pass their own data context to the view.

Think of it as the following:

**User Control**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" ... />
```

**View 1**

```
<LocalViews:CarsGrid />
```

View 1's Model

```
...
public ObservableCollection<Cars> Cars { get; }
...
```

**View 2**

```
<LocalViews:CarsGrid />
```

View 2's Model

```
...
public ICollectionView Cars { get; }
...
```

i.e. the difference between the two view models is that they provide the collection that is bound to the data grid under different types.

I wanted to extract a common interface between the two view models, because I don't feel comfortable not having any requirements to the (indirect) view model which can be bound to this view model-less user control.

The issue is - I could not find a common base class or interface between `ObservableCollection` and `ICollectionView`. Is my approach wrong?

Answer (score -2):

Because ObservableCollection is a collection while ICollectionView is an Interface to a view of collection they do not share a common interface.

You should use one of the interfaces that ObservableCollection implements instead.

```
public ObservableCollection<Cars> Cars { get; }
public ICollection<Cars> Cars { get; } //this is implemented by observablecollection
```

You may want to try something like this

VM1

```
private ObservableCollection<T> _cars; 
public IEnumerable Cars { get { return _cars; } }
```

VM2

```
private List<T> _cars;
public IEnumerable Cars { get { return _cars; } }
```

So both VMs exposes the same property.